# How to make a script switching Active Camera to orthographic mode?

Tags: scripting, camera

how to make a script Active Camera to orthographic 
don’t want to turn on the camera every time and then orthographic

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()
bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho()
```

dont work (((

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

scene.camera.data.type = 'ORTHO' # set to ortho
```

and to perspective

```
scene.camera.data.type = 'PERSP' # set to perspectve
```